# Cutting figures into parts of equal size and form

Tags: geometry

How to cut figures 4 and 5 into 2 parts of the same **sizes and forms**? Cutting is allowed by drawing lines **along sides or diagonals** only, as demonstrated by the example below.

Example of cutting into 2 parts
[image: Example of cutting into 2 parts.]

In figure 4, each part must have 24 / 2 = 12 squares.

In figure 5, each part must have 22 / 2 = 11 squares.

[image: Figure 4 and Figure 5]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using shape clues on the farthest edges.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD6SU.png)